# How to store this event in a variable C#

Tags: c#

This program iterates a formula ( n^2 - 100n + 900) a thousand times  and prints every iteration.

I've iterated from n = 1 so i Know that when n = 11, result becomes negative (-79) and when n = 90, result turns positive.

I need to print that but I'm struggling with the *if* part

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm2od.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Tarea_4_Programa_1
{
    // Formula = n^2 - 100n + 900
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double n = 1; // n in    n^2 - 100n + 900
            double y = 0; // result of  the formula
            double firstchange =0; // first change of sign
            double secondchange = 0;  //second change of sign

            // Iterates the formula  n^2 - 100n + 900  with n = 1 to 1000
            for (int i = 0; i <=1000; i++)
            {
                 y = Math.Pow(n, 2) - 100*n + 900;
                 n = n + 1;
                 if (y < 0)
                 {
                     firstchange = n;
                 }
                 else if (y > 0)
                 {
                     secondchange = n;
                 }

                 Console.WriteLine("When n is " + (n - 1)+ " the result is " + y);



            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("When n is " + firstchange + " result becomes negative");
            Console.WriteLine("When n  is  " + secondchange + "result becomes positive");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What specifically are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know when the value of `y` changes its sign.

```
double y = 0;
bool wasNegative = false;
bool wasPositive = true;

// Iterates the formula  n^2 - 100n + 900  with n = 1 to 1000
for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++)
{
    y = Math.Pow(n, 2) - 100 * n + 900;
    if (y < 0 && wasPositive)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Y changed from Positive to Negative. n = {0}", n);
        wasNegative = true;
        wasPositive = false;
    }
    if (y >= 0 && wasNegative)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Y changed from Negative to Positive. n = {0}", n);
        wasPositive = true;
        wasNegative = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Now i just need to see how to print that outside the for

Comment: Just declare a `List<string>` outside the `for` loop, and instead of doing a `Console.WriteLine()` like I have simply add the string to the list. Then outside the `for` loop simply print that list.

Comment: Also I should mention a caveat; I've take `zero` as a positive integer for this solution although in reality zero is neither. But should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to just keep track of the last result, and then do the comparison inside your loop. If we use a `nullable double` to store the result, we can start it at `null` so we don't have to worry about the first comparison matching our default value:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Used to store the last result (starting with null value)
    double? lastResult = null;

    // Iterates 1000 times (from 1 to 1000 inclusive)
    for (int value = 1; value <= 1000; value++)
    {
        double result = Math.Pow(value, 2) - 100 * value + 900;

        if (lastResult != null)
        {
            if (lastResult < 0 && result >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Sign changed from negative to positive when the value became '{value}'");
            }
            else if (lastResult >= 0 && result < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Sign changed from positive to negative when the value became '{value}'");
            }
        }

        lastResult = result;
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I like this answer because it handles the first comparison as well. +1.